# Query Wordpress Posts by string with GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql

I'm have a headless wordpress installation with a React front end that queries wordpress for posts. I'm trying to create a search feature, that allows me to load posts by search term from the url query string (retrieved by using `const searchQuery = window.location.search.split("?q=")[1]`), which gives me the string to search on.

However, I get the error "ERROR: GraphQL error: No post exists with this id:".

My GraphQL query is as follows:

```
 query postQuery($slug: String) {
  postBy(slug: $slug) {
    id
    slug
    status
    title
    content
    blocks {
        tagName
        type
        attributes,
        innerHtml
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried implementing the example here: https://graphql-search-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search-parameters/#fulltext, but it doesn't seem the request is what I need. I have also tried this example: https://docs.wpgraphql.com/getting-started/posts/#arguments, but again, this does not work.

There are two issues here: 1) How do I use the search term from my variable `searchQuery` in my GraphQL request, and 2) How do I form the query correctly, so that the term can be used to search for and return any post with the search term in either the post title or content of the post?

**UPDATE**

I have updated my code with a separate query from the rest of the application, but now receiving the error on the page `GraphQL error: Cannot query field "title" on type "RootQueryToPostConnection". GraphQL error: Cannot query field "content" on type "RootQueryToPostConnection`

```
const SEARCH_QUERY = gql`
        query searchPostQuery($searchStr: String) {
          posts(where: {search: $searchStr}) {
            title
            content
          }
        }
    `;

    const APP_QUERY = gql`
      query appQuery($locationId: MenuLocationEnum!) {
       ...
    }`;

    const searchQuery = window.location.search.split("?q=")[1];
    function App(props) {
      return (
        <ApolloProvider client={graphClient}>
            <Query query={window.location.pathname === "/search-results" ? SEARCH_QUERY : APP_QUERY} variables={{ locationId: "HEADER_MENU", searchStr: searchQuery }}>
              {({ data, loading, error, client }) => {
                if (loading) return "loading...";
                if (error) return <p>ERROR: {error.message}</p>;
                     return (
                  <>
                    <Query query={HEADER_QUERY}>
                      {({ data, client: headerClient }) => {
                      return (
                      <>
                      <Router>
                         ...
                        <SearchResults
                           path="/search-results"
                        />
                      </Router>
                  </>
                 );
                }}
         </Query>
      </ApolloProvider>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search is not standarized ... it depends on implementation, provider intentions etc.

`postBy(slug: $slug)` will return [only one] post identified by key/value, slug in this case

General (found on github) WP search query shape:

```
{
  posts(where: {search: "cats"}) {
    nodes {
      id
      title
      content
    }
  }
}
```

`searchQuery` can be read from location or from `react-router`... you can pass it into query using variables, f.e.:

```
query searchPostQuery($searchStr: String) {
  posts(where: {search: $searchStr) {
    nodes {
      id
      slug
      status
      title
```

...

```
variables = { searchStr: searchQuery };
```

Of course you can test query (before using in frontend) in `/graphiql` - variables can be defined below query.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and code sample. I've updated my code with your suggestion (update added in question above) and simplified the fields to be queried, but now I get the error: GraphQL error: Cannot query field "title" on type "RootQueryToPostConnection". GraphQL error: Cannot query field "content" on type "RootQueryToPostConnection". I've tried searching around, but not sure why I'm receiving this error. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, missing `nodes` "level" ... in playground editor hints possible fields/names/structure